# Jcarousel and a jquery new added script conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, conflict, jcarousel

**There is a conflict with the below code and another jquery code.  i fixed another conflict with ajax tabs already using**

```
 jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(function ($) {
        // jQuery code in here
    });
```

**but discovered another conflict triggered with jcarousel, doing the same doesn't fixed that issue ,any suggestions will be appreciated.**

**Jcarousel Code**

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{$smarty.const._URL}/js/jquery.jcarousel.pack.js"></script>
          {literal}
          <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        size: {/literal}{$total_playingnow}{literal}
    });
  });
  </script>
```

**The new code that triggered conflicts(facebook pop up likebox):**

```
<script type="text/javascript"/>
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function ($) {
//<![CDATA[
jQuery.cookie = function (key, value, options) {

// key and at least value given, set cookie...
if (arguments.length > 1 && String(value) !== "[object Object]") {
options = jQuery.extend({}, options);

if (value === null || value === undefined) {
options.expires = -1;
}

if (typeof options.expires === 'number') {
var days = options.expires, t = options.expires = new Date();
t.setDate(t.getDate() + days);
}

value = String(value);

return (document.cookie = [
encodeURIComponent(key), '=',
options.raw ? value : encodeURIComponent(value),
options.expires ? '; expires=' + options.expires.toUTCString() : '', // use expires attribute, max-age is not supported by IE
options.path ? '; path=' + options.path : '',
options.domain ? '; domain=' + options.domain : '',
options.secure ? '; secure' : ''
].join(''));
}

// key and possibly options given, get cookie...
options = value || {};
var result, decode = options.raw ? function (s) { return s; } : decodeURIComponent;
return (result = new RegExp('(?:^|; )' + encodeURIComponent(key) + '=([^;]*)').exec(document.cookie)) ? decode(result[1]) : null;
};
//]]>

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
if($.cookie('popup_user_login') != 'yes'){
$('#fanback').delay('3000').fadeIn('medium');
$('#fanclose, #fan-exit').click(function(){
$('#fanback').stop().fadeOut('medium');
});
}

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    // jQuery code in here
});
```

can be changed to

```
(function($){

    //code here

})(jQuery)
```

Which should solve conflict issues.

Comment: JCAROUSEL STILL NOT RESPONDING WITH THAT CHANGE BUT THE CODE WORKED AS THE FIRST ONE.

Comment: what i can say that when i remove jquery.mins.js and the fb widget jquery code ; jcarousel resume working (note that am using noconflict for fbk jquery code );i also have a jquery.mins.js v 1.3.2 loded on the header(dynamic header for all pages) and the code for fbk pop up is inserted into the dynamic footer.