# Order by featured DESC not working for a custom variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following functions , I need to update $how so it sort videos by featured videos after the site_views DESC I tried a lot of times but same output is displaying or I get empty output.Thanks in advance. so i need to display only featured videos after site_views.

```
function list_videos($how = 'added', $limit = '15') { // newest, top views, etc etc etc
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pm_videos ORDER BY $how DESC LIMIT $limit");
    $result = '';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

        $results .= "
                <div class=\"item\">
                <a href=\"" . makevideolink($row['uniq_id'], $row['artist'], $row['video_title']) . "\"><img src=\"" . show_thumb($row['uniq_id']) . "\" alt=\"" . $row['video_title'] . "\" class=\"imag\" width=\"107\" height=\"72\" /></a>
                <a href=\"" . makevideolink($row['uniq_id'], $row['artist'], $row['video_title']) . "\" class=\"song_name\">
                <span class=\"artist_name\">" . fewchars($row['artist'] . " - " . $row['video_title'], 30) . "</span>
                </a>
                <span class=\"item_views\">" . pm_number_format($row['site_views']) . " views</span>
                </div>";
    }
    return $results;
}
```

**Well now i updated the code and it's showing featured vidos only but they aren't ordered:**

```
function list_featured_videos($how = 'added', $limit = '15') { // newest, top views, etc etc etc
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT *
FROM `pm_videos`
ORDER BY `pm_videos`.`featured` DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30");
    $result = '';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

        $results .= "
                <div class=\"item\">
                <a href=\"" . makevideolink($row['uniq_id'], $row['artist'], $row['video_title']) . "\"><img src=\"" . show_thumb($row['uniq_id']) . "\" alt=\"" . $row['video_title'] . "\" class=\"imag\" width=\"107\" height=\"72\" /></a>
                <a href=\"" . makevideolink($row['uniq_id'], $row['artist'], $row['video_title']) . "\" class=\"song_name\">
                <span class=\"artist_name\">" . fewchars($row['artist'] . " - " . $row['video_title'], 30) . "</span>
                </a>
                <span class=\"item_views\">" . pm_number_format($row['site_views']) . " views</span>
                </div>";
    }
    return $results;
};
```

and calling it with :

```
$featured = list_featured_videos('added');
```

**Note that using added or site_views rendered the same result.**

Comment: This question should be updated to ask what you really need: a way to display only featured videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869304/order-by-desc-not-working-for-custom-variable-how), you need a new, separate function for the display of featured videos:

Edited as requested:

```
function list_featured_videos($sql) { // newest, top views, etc etc etc
    $query = mysql_query( $sql );
    $result = '';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

        $results .= "
                <div class=\"item\">
                <a href=\"" . makevideolink($row['uniq_id'], $row['artist'], $row['video_title']) . "\"><img src=\"" . show_thumb($row['uniq_id']) . "\" alt=\"" . $row['video_title'] . "\" class=\"imag\" width=\"107\" height=\"72\" /></a>
                <a href=\"" . makevideolink($row['uniq_id'], $row['artist'], $row['video_title']) . "\" class=\"song_name\">
                <span class=\"artist_name\">" . fewchars($row['artist'] . " - " . $row['video_title'], 30) . "</span>
                </a>
                <span class=\"item_views\">" . pm_number_format($row['site_views']) . " views</span>
                </div>";
    }
    return $results;
};
```

Now you can call this using

```
$featured = list_featured_videos('SELECT * FROM pm_videos WHERE featured=1 ORDER BY site_views DESC LIMIT 10');
```

for example.

Comment: unfortunatelly videos are sorted by DESC but still not for only featured but for all videos, may be WHERE featured=1 must be updated to something else?

Comment: Are you sure you're using list_featured_videos() and not list_videos()?

Comment: if only the featured videos have featured=1 in the database, this will work.

Comment: Yes Chris am using list_featured_videos and in database there is other elements using 1-0 parameter

Comment: other elements? What do you mean? How do you determine a featured video if not featured=1?

Comment: Chris i just added a second part to my question with some new code editing plz review it ,and i mean other elements the column categories ,and there is for example category restricted taken param enum (0,1)

Comment: Also i suugest to remove the $how and $limit and assign list_featured_videos with $query ,so we can have more options to use and exact result?

Comment: That's one way to accomplish it...but you dont want to `ORDER BY featured`. ORDER BY controls the order. You want `WHERE featured=1 ORDER BY somethingelse`.

Comment: well how to use function `list_featured_videos = $query = mysql_query etc`? i mean syntax

Comment: once this syntax will be corrected  i will accept the answer and thanks man for your time!

Comment: altered function to take $sql param

Comment: Chris don't forget to vote up this and the other question thx.

Comment: can you optimize this? : `function list_featured_videos(){$query = mysql_query("SELECT *
FROM pm_videos WHERE featured=1
ORDER BY  DESC
LIMIT 10");`

Comment: Did you see my updated answer? If you use that you should call it like : `list_featured_videos("SELECT * FROM pm_videos WHERE featured=1 ORDER BY site_views DESC LIMIT 10");`

Comment: syntax error on the same line `function list_featured_videos("SELECT * FROM pm_videos WHERE featured=1 ORDER BY site_views DESC LIMIT 10");`

Comment: Syntax error? I don't follow. This is becoming a part time job.

Comment: lol the code you just posted here have a syntax error chris;i may ask you for some paid jobs if you resolve this!

Comment: No, no, the function definition is one thing. That is in the answer above. You CALL the function like this: `$someVariable = list_featured_videos("SELECT * FROM pm_videos WHERE featured=1 ORDER BY site_views DESC LIMIT 10");`

Comment: Thanks it's still showing non featured videos ordered by DESC but your code is perfect.know what i think featured=1 is not working this is the issues..

Comment: so what we can replace it(featured=1) with?

Comment: i update code to : `$featured = list_featured_videos('SELECT * FROM pm_videos WHERE site_views>0 ORDER BY featured DESC LIMIT 10');` but featured videos not ordered  and actually this is my question from the beginning!

Comment: It's your database... you tell me how to distinguish a featured video if not featured=1.  Just don't order by featured... makes no sense I think.

Comment: you have right ! i have to order by site views DESC , but the WHERE clause is ignored for featured =1 because i can't see any featured videos loaded!

Comment: I got the answer myself! can you guess what it is ? it's on the call code

Comment: the answer is above vote it up plz , i will accept your answer because you maked me on the right path thanks thanks thanks! and the secret was to add "" that way featured="1"

Comment: Ahh that means that "featured" isn't a numeric data type, but it should be :p

Comment: well i said that code must work so focused on that detail and finally it worked.again thx man

Comment: take a look here when you are free you may find out the solution cuze you re great!:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20846625/jcarousel-and-a-jquery-new-added-script-conflict

Answer (score 1):

Changing:

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pm_videos ORDER BY $how DESC LIMIT $limit");
```

to

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pm_videos ORDER BY site_views DESC LIMIT $limit");
```

Should work based on what can be seen there (your code currently orders by added DESC) in your example code.........

Is this one of the combinations you've tried?

Comment: yes it's not showing the featured videos but all videos ordered DESC

Answer (score 0):

```
$featured = list_featured_videos('SELECT * FROM pm_videos  WHERE featured="1" ORDER BY site_views DESC LIMIT 10');
```